# want to learn new vocabularies which mean "the famous product of a region"

Tags: vocabulary

Given that there are three big cities A, B, and C in Country Z. 
People in city A raise some special crops for the making breads, "Golden crown". "Golden crown" are well-known in this city only, no one can find these breads in cities B and C.
Given that situation, I want to learn some new vocabularies that have same meaning as "the famous product of a region".
Is it speciality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Speciality of A* or *A speciality* is, as you guess, probably the most common term in ordinary use. (*Speciality* is more often *specialty* in the US—just three syllables, with a single stress on the first.)

> Gooey Butter Cake and Toasted Ravioli are St. Louis specialties.

*Tradition* or *traditional dish* are also used.

> Haggis is a Scottish tradition whose appeal is not always apparent to Southrons.

There are also many legal terms such as *Protected Designation of Origin* under which countries and international agreements restrict the use of geographic designations and traditional names; you may read about these [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_indications_and_traditional_specialities_in_the_European_Union). But these terms will not arise very often in ordinary conversation.

Comment: Gooey butter cake'll kill ya dead. But you'll enjoy the ride.

Comment: @oaker Everybody who eats gooey butter cake dies. But everybody who eats kale dies, too. You pays your money and you takes your choice.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to learn some new vocabularies that have same meaning as "the
>   famous product of a region".

In English, one can also say that a city or region is *known for* something, which *can* be a product but does not have to be:

**New Orleans is known for its music.**

**Hershey, Pennsylvania is known for its chocolate.**

**Munich is known for its beer.**

**Siberia is known for its winters.**

**North Carolina is known for its tobacco.**

**Oklahoma is known for its tornadoes.**

**Switzerland is known for its banking system.**